# Which function is called when a screen is opened after popping from navigation stack?

Tags: flutter, navigation

I have 2 screens - screen A and screen B. I navigate from screen A to screen B.
I want to take some particular action when I am coming BACK to screen A by popping out screen B from the navigation stack. 
I know I can use `didUpdateWidge` but I can't figure out an efficient way of doing it.
Is using `Inherited Widget` the correct way here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Navigator.push[Named]` returns a `Future` that completes when screen B pops. So add the code you want to execute after the pop to `then`.

```
  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/someRoute').then((_) {/* do stuff here */});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [WillPopScope](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/WillPopScope-class.html). This widget allows to catch back button press.

Comment: That is when you press back from screen B, I want to detect that screen A is opening again.

Comment: MaterialApp allows to pass NavigatorObservers. So you can handle Pop events and do some action when previousRoute is that one what you need.